# Why does print() and logger object streaming to console outputs in unexpected order?

Tags: python, logging, python-logging

I'm trying to use a print function before and after using two logger objects that will stream the output to the console.
Thing is i'm getting a really messy output which is not in expected order.

I've tried changing the print() to logger_object.info() and it works well as intended.

The full code with the unexpected output :

```
import logging

# Create logger objects and set  level
loggerA = logging.getLogger()
loggerA.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

loggerB = logging.getLogger()
loggerB.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# Set log output format
log_format = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(name)s - %(message)s', datefmt='%m/%d/%Y - %I:%M:%S %p')

# Create a console stream handler
stream_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
stream_handler.setFormatter(log_format)

# Add handlers to the loggers
loggerA.addHandler(stream_handler)
loggerB.addHandler(stream_handler)


def main():
    for i in range(10):
        print('Starting loop number {}'.format(i))
        loggerA.info("loop number {}".format(i))
        loggerB.info("loop number {}".format(i))
        print('Finished loop number {}'.format(i))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Adding loggerC object to replace print() with loggerC.info() :

```
...
loggerC = logging.getLogger()
loggerC.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
...
def main():
    for i in range(10):
        loggerC('Starting loop number {}'.format(i))
        loggerA.info("loop number {}".format(i))
        loggerB.info("loop number {}".format(i))
        loggerC('Finished loop number {}'.format(i))
...
```

The first case using print() unexpected output is :

```
04/06/2019 - 10:10:34 AM - INFO - loggerA - loop number 1
Starting loop number 1
04/06/2019 - 10:10:34 AM - INFO - loggerB - loop number 1
04/06/2019 - 10:10:34 AM - INFO - loggerA - loop number 2
04/06/2019 - 10:10:34 AM - INFO - loggerB - loop number 2
Finished loop number 1
Starting loop number 2
Finished loop number 2
Starting loop number 3
Finished loop number 3
04/06/2019 - 10:10:34 AM - INFO - loggerA - loop number 3
04/06/2019 - 10:10:34 AM - INFO - loggerB - loop number 3
```

The second case using loggerC.info() instead of print() which is an expected output :

```
04/06/2019 - 10:12:21 AM - INFO - loggerC - Starting loop number 1
04/06/2019 - 10:12:21 AM - INFO - loggerA - loop number 1
04/06/2019 - 10:12:21 AM - INFO - loggerB - loop number 1
04/06/2019 - 10:12:21 AM - INFO - loggerC - Finished loop number 1
04/06/2019 - 10:12:21 AM - INFO - loggerC - Starting loop number 2
04/06/2019 - 10:12:21 AM - INFO - loggerA - loop number 2
04/06/2019 - 10:12:21 AM - INFO - loggerB - loop number 2
04/06/2019 - 10:12:21 AM - INFO - loggerC - Finished loop number 2
04/06/2019 - 10:12:21 AM - INFO - loggerC - Starting loop number 3
04/06/2019 - 10:12:21 AM - INFO - loggerA - loop number 3
04/06/2019 - 10:12:21 AM - INFO - loggerB - loop number 3
04/06/2019 - 10:12:21 AM - INFO - loggerC - Finished loop number 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You issue is likely a problem of [standard streams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams). By default `print` uses `std::out` and `logger.info` uses `std::err`. Both streams [are bound to your terminal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redirection_(computing)) but they may have different `flush` refresh or triggers.

This is why your outputs are mixed in, functions write to different streams and they are flushed differently to the terminal, leading to an apparent inconsistent result.

Changing your first code to force `logger.info` to use the same stream than `print` solve your problem:

```
import sys
stream_handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
```

Now, it returns the correct output:

```
-- Starting loop number 0
04/06/2019 - 07:41:34 AM - INFO - root - loop number 0
04/06/2019 - 07:41:34 AM - INFO - root - loop number 0
-- Finished loop number 0
-- Starting loop number 1
04/06/2019 - 07:41:34 AM - INFO - root - loop number 1
04/06/2019 - 07:41:34 AM - INFO - root - loop number 1
-- Finished loop number 1
-- Starting loop number 2
04/06/2019 - 07:41:34 AM - INFO - root - loop number 2
04/06/2019 - 07:41:34 AM - INFO - root - loop number 2
-- Finished loop number 2
-- Starting loop number 3
04/06/2019 - 07:41:34 AM - INFO - root - loop number 3
04/06/2019 - 07:41:34 AM - INFO - root - loop number 3
-- Finished loop number 3
```

Because both `print` and `logger.info` feed the same stream in the right order whenever it is flushed to your terminal, the result is correct.

You can also keep [different streams](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/sys.html#sys.stdout) and force the `std::out` stream to be [flushed explicitly](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/io.html#io.IOBase.flush):

```
def main():
    for i in range(10):
        print('-- Starting loop number {}'.format(i))
        # Force std::out stream (fed by print) to be flushed to the terminal
        # before logger feeds std::err and also flushes
        sys.stdout.flush() 
        loggerA.info("loop number {}".format(i))
        loggerB.info("loop number {}".format(i))
        print('-- Finished loop number {}'.format(i))
        sys.stdout.flush()
```

This second version also produces the intended result.

Also remember than `logger` is by definition [thread-safe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_safety) but `print` is not. If you are about to make a module using thread, only use `logger` to trace the execution.